# Trying to merge overlapping rectangles using two for loops but getting error when removing original rectangles

Tags: python, list, iteration, ocr, rectangles

```
new_blobs = []

for blob in list(blobs):

    expanded_blob = Blob(blob.x - merge_threshold, blob.y - merge_threshold, blob.width + merge_threshold, blob.height + merge_threshold)

    for other_blob in list(blobs):
        if other_blob != blob and expanded_blob.intersects(other_blob):
            new_blob = Blob(blob.x, blob.y, blob.width, blob.height)
            new_blob.expand_to_contain_blob(other_blob)
            new_blobs.append(new_blob)
            blobs.remove(other_blob)
            blobs.remove(blob)

return blobs + new_blobs
```

This causes this error

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I am trying to merge any of the rectangles that ate close enough, first I check collision with an expanded rectangle and then I merge them. blob has a method for expanding so that the other rectangle fits inside so I create a new rectangle based on one of the rectangles and have it expand to fit over the other one then I want to get rid of the two rectangles from which it was formed.

The problem is that I can't remove an item from a list I am iterating over so I made a copy, firstly that means that I will now iterate over rectangles that have been deleted and try to delete them again, I tried to keep a list of used rectangles and check every time if the rectangle is used before checking it which I really did not want to do but it returned the same error.

Really stuck on this one. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`list(blobs)` is temporary conversion

you need give `list_blobs =list(blobs)` and then loop it

use `list_blobs.remove()`

```
  for blob in list_blobs:
    expanded_blob = Blob(blob.x, blob.y, blob.width + merge_threshold, blob.height + merge_threshold)

    for other_blob in list_blobs:
        if other_blob != blob and expanded_blob.intersects(other_blob):
            new_blob = Blob(blob.x, blob.y, blob.width, blob.height)
            new_blob.expand_to_contain_blob(other_blob)
            new_blobs.append(new_blob)
            list_blobs.remove(other_blob)
            list_blobs.remove(blob)

return list_blobs + new_blobs
```

Comment: But then you are still deleting objects from the list that you are iterating over but replacing the list with another list.